# Как реализовать двухмерной массив? И как его заполнить при помощи клавиатуры?

Tags: c++

Я питался написать сам код:

```
...const int array Size=10
int a[array Size];
//Тут должен быть цикл заполнения массива, но я его не придумал.
```

Куча ошибок выбивает по типу:

> Должна быть ';' перед Size и т.д.

Напишите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать в С++.

Весь код:

```
  #include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0,"ukr");
    int i,j,n=15;
    int array a[i][j];
    for (i=0;i<=2+n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=5+n;j++)
        {
            a[i,j]=pow(n,i+j)+pow(n,i-j)-(i-j)*(i-j);
            cout<<"a["<<i<<","<,j<<"]="<<a[i,j];
        }
    }
    systym("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Простите, но по тому, что вы написали, понятно, что отвечать вам бессмысленно. Простите для начала [эту книгу](https://www.litmir.me/bd/?b=174394&p=1). Описание массивов начинается с 77 страницы.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что перед тем как задавать вопрос по языку, надо хотя бы в **минимальной** степени знать его синтаксис.

Comment: А зачем вы придумываете стандартные алгоритмы? Нужно взять стандартное решение и изучить его. Куча есть учебников онлайн, например https://code-live.ru/tag/cpp-manual/

Comment: @Harry я одномерный массив понимаю как написать, но двухмерный не очень понимаю...

Comment: `int array_name[first_dim_size][second_dim_size];` В той же книге страница 82. Да что вы, в самом деле, не можете потратить денек-другой и пролистать ее? Все сразу ускорится. Вы же сейчас напоминаете человека, который взялся писать повесть, но все время спрашивает, как пишется даже не то или иное слово - а буква...

Comment: Да, издание книги можете поискать повсежее, кажется, уже было седьмое... Ну, чтоб с более современным С++ познакомиться. Вот это - http://www.dialektika.com/books/978-5-8459-1952-6.html или, например, эту книгу: http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9909445-6-5.html

Comment: @Harry что-то не так до сих пор... вибивает:_error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "a" и *error C2065: a: необъявленный идентификатор*

Comment: Откуда я знаю, **что** вы там вводили и компилировали...

Comment: @Harry добавил весь код...

Comment: Ну вы еще напишите `int хочу массив с именем a[5][10];`. Вы читали упомянутые страницы? Где там слово `array`? На... словом, зачем вы его туда упорно пишете? Это - `a[i,j]` - тоже неверно. `a[i][j]`. Простите, мне можете больше не писать - где взять учебник, я вам написал.

Comment: Ну нельзя же так... я заржал так, что вокруг народ начал озираться. "- В сад, в сад! - Вы там будете объяснять? - Нет, вы там будете читать учебник..." Почти по "Троим в лодке"...

Comment: @Harry, простите.. но в то время у меня не было времени читять, и ещё и искать разархиватор... Простите, спасибо за учебник.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример генерации и вывода массива.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define N 3
#define M 4

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int matrix[N][M]; 
     //случайным образом
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j]=rand()%50;
    }
    }
    //C клавиатуры
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        cin >> matrix[i][j];
    }
    }


     cout << "Matrix: "<< endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {

        cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    }


}
```